# Given that $|z+w| = 1$ and $|z^2+w^2| = 14$, find the smallest possible value of $|w^3+z^3|$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $w$ and $z$ two complex numbers such that $|z+w| = 1$ and $|z^2+w^2| = 14$. Find the smallest possible value of $|w^3+z^3|$,  where |.| denotes the absolute value of a complex number, given by $|a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

**My working**

$|w^3+z^3| = |w+z||w^2+z^2-zw| = |(w+z)^2-3wz|$

Using triangle inequalities,

$|(w+z)^2-3wz| \ge ||w+z|^2-3|wz|| = |1-3|wz||$

$|z+w|^2 = |z^2+w^2+2wz|$

again applying triangle inequality

$|z^2+w^2|+2|wz|\ge1\ge||w^2+z^2|-2|wz||$

solving for range of |wz| I get

$15/2\ge |wz|\ge13/2$
then i getting the incorrect range of of $|z^3+w^2|$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the given conditions as $z+w=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$ and $z^2+w^2=14\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi},$
for some angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. Now
$$\begin{align}z^3 +w^3&=\tfrac12(z+w)[3(z^2+w^2)-(z+w)^2]\\&=21\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta+\phi)}-\tfrac12\mathrm e^{3\mathrm i\theta}\\&=21\cos(\theta+\phi)-\tfrac12\cos3\theta+\mathrm i[21\sin(\theta +\phi)-\tfrac12\sin3\theta].\end{align}$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}|z^3+w^3|^2&=[21\cos(\theta+\phi)-\tfrac12\cos3\theta]^2+[21\sin(\theta +\phi)-\tfrac12\sin3\theta]^2\\&=441.25-21\cos(\phi-2\theta).\end{align}$$
This is minimized when $\cos(\phi-2\theta)=1$, namely when
$$|z^3+w^3|=\surd420.25=20.5.$$

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica 14 answers

```
z = x + I*y; w = u + I*v; NMinimize[ComplexExpand[{Abs[w^3 + z^3]^2, 
Abs[z + w]^2 == 1 && Abs[z^2 + w^2]^2 == 14^2}], {x, y, u, v}]
```

$$\{420.25,\{x -> -2.05877, y -> -0.404213, u -> 3.04004, v -> 0.596871\}\} $$

I have strong doubts concerning its symbolic solution.